# LoadBalancer or Nodeport service not connecting to pod inside minikube from localhost

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-nodeport

I'm trying to use LoadBalancer as a service to a pod. The container inside the pod (single container pod) is listening to port 8080 for receiving packets over UDP. I have checked the container manually and it is doing fine its part. However I'm unable to send packets from my host machine to my pod which is inside minikube cluster after creating a LoadBalancer service.

Here is my pod and service yaml file.
I want to send packets to my pod inside the cluster. I've created a service which you can have look into.

The service does listen but I really don't understand where the packets are forwarded after I send it to externalIP:nodePort.

For POD

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: tstream-deb
  labels:
    app: tstream-deb
spec:
  containers:
  - name: tstream-deb
    image: tstream-deb
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
      protocol: UDP
```

Service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: tstream-deb
  labels:
    app: tstream-deb
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
      nodePort: 30001
      protocol: UDP
  selector:
    name: tstream-deb
    app: tsream-deb
~
```

So my pod basically listens for a packet/message and does something in Golang, which I tested locally as well as within the container which works exactly fine.

How can I interact with my pod from localhost to inside of minikube cluster. I've tried minikube tunnel too but of no help.

Comment: your `selector` in the `Service` resource doesn't seem right. It should only have the `app: tsream-deb` selector, please update your question to add result for `kubectl describe svc tstream-deb`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the issue is with using `<externalIP>:<nodePort>` as network address.

It should be either

```
<externalIP>:<servicePort>(80)
```

or

```
<nodeIP>:<nodePort>(30001)
```

You can also use port-forward from host machine to check the services

```
kubectl port-forward svc/tstream-deb 3000:80
```

With this setting use `localhost:3000` as the network address